# Android Studio Java Library Path

Tags: java, android

I am developing and android application with an imported library RobotRaconteur and have imported it to where Android Studio recognizes all of its functions/ methods.  I can compile without errors however I receive an error when running the application:

```
 Process: com.example.michael.smartbutton, PID: 1879
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RobotRaconteurJavaNative-android from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.smartbutton-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.michael.smartbutton-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
```

I read in the library's documentation that you need to place "the native libraries in the java.library.path for the Java runtime.  I believe this may be my underlying issue as I have placed this .dll file in various filders.  (Also, the library's folders contain two .so files that are imported near the Jar file if that helps anyone). Any other ideas? Thanks!